# Use of std::declval on fundamental types

Tags: c++, c++11

The following code fails to compile when the template parameter `T` is a fundamental type such as `int` (on gcc 4.8).  Is this standard conforming behaviour?  My understanding of `std::declval` was that it always resolves to either a `T&&` or `T&`.

```
template <class T>
void foo(T&& val)
{
  std::cout << noexcept(std::declval<typename std::decay<T>::type>() = val);
}

struct bar { };
bar b;
foo(b); // okay

int a;
foo(a); // error: using xvalue (rvalue reference) as lvalue
```

The error occurs at the point of assigning `val` to the `std::declval` expression.

It works if I remove the `std::decay` and use `std::declval<T>` directly, but I'm not sure why.  The decayed type should just be `int` and so `std::declval<int>()` should have a return type of `int&&` shouldn't it?

Comment: It seems you're trying to duplicate the function of `std::is_nothrow_copy_assignable`?

Comment: Almost.  If `T` is an lvalue reference I want to check for nothrow copy assign, but if `T` is an rvalue reference I want to check for nothrow move assign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to assign to an rvalue. `std::declval<int>()` correctly returns a type `int&&`. It has no name, so it's an rvalue (more precisely, xvalue) of type `int`. You're then trying to assign `val` into this rvalue, which is illegal for fundamental types.

Here's a [live example](http://ideone.com/6s68x4) demonstrating the problem in simplified form (without `declval`).

Comment: +1 Inside foo, the type of val is int& and without decay, declval gives you int&, too. With decay, you get int& ->int -> int&&.

Comment: Ahh, of course.  I should be using `std::declval<std::add_lvalue_reference<T>::type>()` instead.  Thanks!

Comment: @marack or just `std::declval<T&>()` :P

Comment: @Simple yes, good point.  I forgot that `T&& &` collapses to `T&`.  Thanks.

Comment: @marack Not to mention the fact that the `T` in your example will never be of type `U&&` for any `U`; it will either be a non-reference `U`, or `U&`.

Comment: @Angew I didn't provide an example instantiation where `T` is `U&&`, but that is perfectly possible (and happens in the real code).  For example, `foo(std::move(b))`.  In the end, `std::declval<T&>()` was unsuitable as well, since `T` retains cv-qualifiers.  As verbose as it seems, the final solution seems to be `std::declval<typename std::add_lvalue_reference<typename std::decay<T>::type>::type>()`.

Comment: @marack In a universal reference (that is `T&&` where `T` is a template parameter), `T` can *never* be deduced to `U&&` for any `U`. If the argument is an l-value of type `U`, `T` is deduced to `U&`. If the argument is an r-value of type `U`, `T` is deduced to plain `U`. Of course, the type of the function parameter will then be `U&&`, but that's because it's `T&&` originally.

Comment: @Angew Ah, yes you're right - the example in my comment is bad.  This template is called by other templates, and `T` is set explicitly with the parameter being implicitly converted.  So the invocation often ends up something like `foo<U&&>(std::forward(val))` where `T` is explicitly made an rvalue reference.